# How to make a new List in Scala from previous one by calculating all intermediate value?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of `String`s in Scala. I want to make a new list in which each element is corresponding element in the previous list, appended with as many `\n`s as much there are cummulatively before that element of list. Something like this:

```
List("a\nb\nc","\nd","e") => List("a\nb\nc","\n\n\nd","\n\n\ne")
```

No new `\n`s appended to first one, 2 extra appended to second (as first one had 2) and three (cummulative of first and second) to third one.

I find this problem to lie somewhat in between `fold` and `yield` constructs.
What is the best way to achieve this without using any mutable variables or so in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no one forbids you to use List as a fold's accumulator and carry your state there. I will count "f" chars since it is much simpler for debugging:

```
val lf = List("afbfc", "fd", "e")
def count_char(s: String) = s.count(_ == 'f')
val fold_res = lf.foldLeft((List[String](), 0)) ((acc, next_string) =>
  (("f" * acc._2 + next_string) +: acc._1,
    count_char(next_string) + acc._2))
fold_res._1.reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def doTheThing (a: List[String]): List[String] = 
  ((0,List.empty[String]) /: a) {(acc, x) =>
    (acc._1 + x.count(_ == '\n')) -> (acc._2 ++ List("\n"*acc._1 + x))
  }._2
```

Answer (score 2):

Much the same as the others, in two passes (so slower) but maybe clearer.

```
// calculate the cumulative number of \n we've seen so far
val ns = xs.scanLeft(0){(a, s) => a + s.count(e => e == 'f')}
//> ns  : List[Int] = List(0, 2, 3)

// prepend that many "f" to the elements of the original list
val ys = (ns zip xs).map { case (l,r) => "f"*l ++ r }
//> ys  : List[String] = List(afbfc, fffd, fffe)
```